# WSGI-applications with *.pyo format

Tags: python, apache, wsgi

I am trying to start WSGi-application under Apache and I have a strange issue:
When I use python files with *.py format everything look fine, but when I use same files with *.pyo format (without *.py at all) I have the following message in Apache log-file:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=27595): Target WSGI script '/usr/local/nb/wwwroot/wsgi_test/main.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=27595): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/local/nb/wwwroot/wsgi_test/main.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/nb/wwwroot/wsgi_test/main.wsgi", line 11, in ?
     import service_env
  ImportError: No module named service_env
```

Apache version: Apache/2.0.63
Python version: Python 2.4
  WSGI version: 3.3
        System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5

Here is my apache conf-file:

```
WSGIPythonOptimize 2

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/nb/wwwroot/wsgi_test
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache/service4supl-errors.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache/service4supl-custom.log combine

    <Directory /usr/local/nb/wwwroot/wsgi_test>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias /test /usr/local/nb/wwwroot/wsgi_test/main.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: python bytecode formats change with each version.  was the `.pyo` compiled by tha same version of python as used by your mod_wsgi?

Comment: I cannot say exactly because I uses third-party modules and I have only *.pyo files. But I think the answer is "yes" because I am sure that this modules works fine on the another servers (which same environment).

Comment: Where is service_env located? Are you sure it is not a sys.path issue? I know of no reason why .pyc/.pyo files shouldn't work. Only the .wsgi file should need to be actual code.

Comment: It located in the same directory where *.wsgi file located. And I am sure this is not a sys.path issue. Because when I try to import something test file with *.py everything is fine, but when I just change file into *.pyo format I get the error above.